# How to iteratively formally test many variables for normality in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, p-value

So I am working with several hundred variables that I would like to see whether or not they are normally distributed. For the formal test, I am using an Anderson-Darling formal test for normality. This is what I have so far:

```
result <- list()
for(i in seq(dim(newdata)[2])) {
    result <- append(result, ad.test(newdata[[i]]))
}
```

This pops up a list with several $p.value results. I'm hoping to call all of the variables and their $p.value results so that I can rank the p-values and see which ones are low enough to reject the assumption of normality. Any advice on how to call the variable names and associated p-values from this code, or any code that could help with this, is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: That seems like a pretty useless endeavor. 1. You can't proof that a sample originates from a normal distribution. 2. You have a massive multiple testing problem. 3. Why are you even trying to find samples from normal distributions? 4. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/11849

Comment: 1) You can prove that a sample's distribution follows a normal distribution 2) Each distribution should be tested separately from each other 3 and 4) this sample size is small